# Will too many overridden css rules lead to performance issues

Tags: customization, css, performance

I am customizing the avada theme for my needs. Since the theme gives many options to style the fronted via its admin panel, I have to write many lines of simple css code for custom elements etc. Based on the fact that this site won't be client related this is just ok for me.

I am just wondering, if too many css rules will lead to performance issues? I know that written rules will increase the impact of the kb, which has to be loaded. With W3Total Cache this shouldn't be too bad, because it'd reduce the size just to a little amount of kb.

But can overriding too many of css rules still lead to performance issues even with a caching plugin? Just to get a sense: I am speaking about 3-4k extra written lines.

If so, is there any option to maintain these rules directly in the theme? Yes, of course I am using a child theme ;)

Best Regards!

Answer (score -1):

If you care about performance then don't use Avada theme.  It is total garbage when it comes to performance.  The demo has 27,000 lines/5244 Rules of CSS and 2 dozen inline style sheets.

In my experience a complex website with 30-40 different templates could be around 1000 rules and 5-6k lines of css.

No cache plugin will save the client from a .7mb css file.  Most people especially theme authors in the WordPress community do not take this stuff serious.  Speed is king.